# Alternative to outline property for IE 6 / 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, outline

I was happily using [`outline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/outline) property until I came to know that it is [not supported in IE 6 / 7](http://work.arounds.org/issue/55/outline-property-not-supported-ie6-or-ie7/).
I tried but couldnt find any alternative.
 How to achieve same effect as `outline` property in IE 6 / 7 ?

---

**Edit:**
I want to apply it to `input`,`radio` and `checkbox`. So workaround should (hopefully) work with all of this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you specifically need an outline rather than a border?

Comment: @Jamie: Yes. I am applying it to all input/radio.checkbox. Looking for exact effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a rule i try to avoid using outline, for the reason you have just discovered.

A potential work around.

```
.element_name {
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:-1px;
}
```

Comment: I think its not working with radio and checkbox. http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/5SkCA/

Comment: @Ajinkya It should work in IE 6/7. Use `outline` and apply this fix only in an IE-specific stylesheet and it will be fine.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: Okay. Let me try.

Comment: This seems to work, however I encountered a problem with this. Expect unexpected wrapping behaviour when applying this method on an inline element.